# how to stop python threads on my command?

Tags: python, multithreading, api, python-requests, stress-testing

I'm trying to make a script to test my api. it should create X threads and every thread should send a request to my server and log data until i will stop it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or some comand)

how can i implement stoping ?
Thank you!

my code:

```
import requests, os, time, sys
from threading import Thread

myThreads = 5

log = ["errorCode, before, after"]
def addToLog(errorCode, before, after):
    log.append(str(errorCode)+","+str(before)+","+str(after))

def saveLogToFile():
    logFile = open('log.csv', 'w')
    for line in log:
        logFile.write(line+"\n")

def sendRequest():
    before = time.time()
    response = requests.post("https://localhost/api", data= {
        "action": 0,
        "id": 1,
        })
    after = time.time()
    json = response.json()
    return json["errorCode"], before, after

def work():
    while True:
        errorCode, before, after = sendRequest()
        addToLog(errorCode, before, after)

for i in range(myThreads):
    t = Thread(target=work)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

saveLogToFile()
```

Comment: try sys.exit(0) from sys package.

Comment: What os do you use? In *nix like system, you can use `pkill python` to kill the python process, thus all the threads within it.

Comment: What happens now when you run your program? As you have already set `daemon=True` in your threads, they should exit as soon as you shut down your main program.  If you have problems stopping this program, it might be that the main thread is reluctant to die when you hit control C.

Comment: @Hannu the problem is that seems my script is doing nothing, cuz programs just stops in 1 second after starting

Comment: It seems that your problem isn't making your program _stop_ but keeping it _running_ long enough.  Do you know that the program exits when the main thread exits?  Your main thread exits almost instantly, all it does is write the single string in `log` to a file and then it's done.  Perhaps you want to consider join()ing your threads.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone hm, and how can i fix it ?
i'm not very familiar with python :(

Answer (score 0):

To keep your program running long enough for all your workers to do all their work, "join" the worker threads.  "Joining" a thread is jargon for waiting for the thread to finish running.  There are two straightforward options for joining threads in your program.  First, the hard way:

```
worker_threads = []
for i in range(myThreads):
    t = Thread(target=work)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    worker_threads.append(t)

saveLogToFile()
for t in worker_threads:
    t.join()
```

Next, the easy way.  Non-daemon threads are automatically joined after the main thread exits.  So just stop making your threads daemons:

```
for i in range(myThreads):
    t = Thread(target=work)
    t.start()

saveLogToFile()
```

Comment: Thank you!
and how i can make script work untill i press ctrl+c ?(and saveLogToFile before shutting down script)

Comment: I think either of the variations I suggested will run until you interrupt them (because your threads run forever - or until an unhandled exception, at least).  As for saveToLogFile, I suggest you replace your list with a Queue.Queue, have your workers put items into that, and start one more thread that gets items from it and writes them to the file.